# How to access ember model in on("init") in object controller

Tags: ember.js

How to access ember model in on("init") in object controller? Its undefined in this case:

```
  inititalise: function () {

    // this.model is undefined

  }.on("init"),
```

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is that you can't. Controllers are instantiated by the container before the route has had a chance to set the model on the controller. If this object controller is a controller set up automatically for you by Ember, you're not going to be able to access the model during initialization. Try observing the `model` property instead.

I can't really find any documentation in the guides on this, so [I'll link you to the source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/4863faa3cdc4c8b2602195e31407787ea4a78f45/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1013). If you read the source for the `setup` function, you'll see that `generateController()` is called and then `setupController()` is called some time later. Essentially, the controller is created, Ember does some work, then the model is set. Ember doesn't set the model for the controller on creation.

Comment: I see, what I need to do is setup the VM as the user interaction is quite different from the model structure. I will just observe the model for changes and then create the properties I need. Seems a bit of work to do just such a simple thing.

Comment: Don't forget that your model can change, which is why it isn't set during initialization. So your logic might need to change and it will probably run more than once. Depending on your use case, the [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) or [resetController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_resetController) route methods might help you out.

Comment: ah setupController looks like what I need after calling super() thanks!