# What is the correct way to access the model from a controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I was wondering what the correct way to access the *model* from the *controller*?

I noticed that in the **init** of the controller the model is still null

#controller.js

```
init(){
  console.log(this.model); // IS NULL
}
```

But the **setupController** method has the populated *model*. Therefore currently I am calling a controller's method from the **setupController** and an passing the model over there. Is this fine?

I was thinking there would be a callback method in the controller which would automatically be called when the controller is setup.

Comment: Here's answer to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332840/how-to-access-ember-model-in-oninit-in-object-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

route.js

```
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll("post");
  },  
  setupController(controller, model){
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
```

This will give console log model which is collection of post object.

controller.js

```
 init(){
  console.log(this.model);
 }
```

We do this most of the times especially if you use RSVP promise 
you chose what will be the model on your controller.

Example

```
 model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      lecture: this.store.findRecord('section', params.section_id).then((section)=>{
        return this.store.createRecord('lecture',{
          section: section
        });
      }),
      section:this.store.findRecord('section', params.section_id),
      course: this.store.query('course',{filter:{section_id:params.section_id}})
    });
  },
  setupController(controller,model){
    controller.set('model', model.lecture);
    controller.set('section', model.section);
    controller.set('course', model.course);

  }
```

Note if you only have just simple model on route

```
 model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('course', params.course_id);
      }
```

and you don`t have to do any setup on controller which is possible this will also give you model on controller.

Comment: Hmmm. I see what you mean. So in other words. What I am doing is not wrong right ?

Answer (score 2):

`setupController` hook method will set model as property to controller.

```
setupController(controller,model){
 this._super(...arguments);
}
```

You can get model just like normal other properties in controller. `this.get('model')`